# Ionic 2: Loading screen does not get dismissed

Tags: ionic2

I have an application made with Ionic 2, The work flow is like this

Case A . When user is using app for the first time

- User Logs in (loading is shown)
- When successfully logged in loading window is hidden and user is forwarded to Dashboard page.
- In dashboard page items are loaded via ajax request.

Case B. When user is already logged in before

- The first screen is Dashboard and items are loaded via ajax request.

**Problem**

In case A, when user logs in and forwarded to DashboardPage, the loading screen doesn't gets dismissed. Sometimes it gets dismissed but most of the time it doesnot? Is this an ionic bug or am I doing something wrong??

Here is my `DashboardPage`

```
//imports here


export class DashboardPage {
    public loadingmsg: any;
    public ajaxRequest: any;

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController, 
        public navParams: NavParams, 
        private webservice: WebService, 
        private loadingCtrl: LoadingController
    )
    {
        this.loadDashboardContents();
    }

    loadDashboardContents(){
        //other codes
        this.loadingmsg = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content:"Loading contents, please wait..."
        });

        this.loadingmsg.present();

        this.ajaxRequest = this.webservice.getDashboardContents(params).subscribe(data => {
            this.loadingmsg.dismiss().then(()=>{
                //other codes to save retrieved data to localstorage.
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
The login method from login page

```
loginUser(){
    this.loading=this.loadingctrl.create({
            content:"Logging in, please wait..."
     });

     this.loading.present();

     this.ajaxRequest = this.webservice.loginUser(params).subscribe(data => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        if(data.status =="ok"){
            this.navctrl.push(DashboardPage).then(()=>{
                const index = this.viewCtrl.index;
                this.navctrl.remove(index);
            });
        }else{
            //show error alert
        }
     }, err =>{
        this.loading.dismiss();
     });

}
```

My Ionic and cordova version information

```
Ionic Framework: 3.5.0
Ionic App Scripts: 1.3.9
Angular Core: 4.1.3
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.3
Node: 6.10.3
OS Platform: Windows 10
Cordova Version: 6.5.0
```

Comment: Maybe there's an error in the request, and the subscription is throwing an error (not being handled in your code)? Could you please set a `debugger` to verify if the `this.loadingmsg.dismiss()...` line is being reached?

Comment: @sebaferreras, no there is no error in the request, I can see proper response from the server in console. `this.loadingmsg.dismiss()` I tested with that too and it reaches there.

Comment: Just for testing purposes, what happens if you don't show a loading in the LoginPage (comment the lines where you show it and where you hide it later), and just show it in the Dashboard? This is just to see if maybe there's a conflict between those two loading instances...

Comment: @sebaferreras, did that too, doesn't make any difference, loading sometimes gets dismissed but not always.

Comment: can you show the login page where you are using `loading`?

Comment: @suraj, please check my update

Comment: maybe the dashboard is pushed before `dismiss` is returned where second loading is called.. maybe do the pushing in `this.loading.dismiss().then(()=>{ 
 //load})`

Comment: @suraj, no even if i disable loading in login page  most of the time doesn't work in dashboardpage

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using loading in my project and it works well in all case. To ensure loading will always dismiss you need to add some code:
1. duration, dismissOnPageChange

```
let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
   content: "",
   duration: 5000, //ms
   dismissOnPageChange: true 
})
```

2. dissmis when ajax call success or error:

```
.subscribe(success=>{
  //some code
  loading.dismiss();
},error=>{
  //some code
  loading.dismiss();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the `this` reference inside your subscribe method. I would try declaring `loadingmsg` locally and removing `this`.

```
loadDashboardContents(){
    //other codes
    let loadingmsg = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content:"Loading contents, please wait..."
    });

    loadingmsg.present();

    this.ajaxRequest = this.webservice.getDashboardContents(params).subscribe(data => {
        loadingmsg.dismiss().then(()=>{
            //other codes to save retrieved data to localstorage.
        });
    });
}
```